# Caesar cypher, shifting chars in for each loop

Tags: java, foreach, caesar-cipher

why doesn't this work properly at all?

```
for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++) { // repeat the core program until all arguments were processed once

            int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); // save given key into int variable
            char[] charArray = args[i].toCharArray(); // argument from String to charArray
            int j = 0;
            for (char c : charArray) { // iterate through the Array by using a for-each loop
                if (Character.isLetter(c)) { // ascertain that only letters are alternated
                    charArray[j] = (char) ((c + k - (int)'a')%26 +(int)'a');// shifting the respective letter by the value the key holds
                }
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println(charArray);
        }
```

Somehow it doesn't work and I can't figure out why, also why can't I replace

```
charArray[j] = (char) ((c + k - (int)'a')%26 +(int)'a');
```

with

````
c = (char) ((c + k - (int)'a')%26 +(int)'a');
```?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Problem might be in args. Below is the code I used to check it.

```
public class C {
public static void main (String [] args){

    Encrypt(new String[]
            {
                    "",
                    "",
                    "3",
                    "abcxyz",
                    "qwedv"
            });

}

public static void Encrypt(String[] args){

    for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++) { // repeat the core program until all arguments were processed once

        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); // save given key into int variable
        char[] charArray = args[i].toCharArray(); // argument from String to charArray
        int j = 0;
        for (char c : charArray) { // iterate through the Array by using a for-each loop
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) { // ascertain that only letters are alternated
                charArray[j] = (char) ((((int)c) + k - (int)'a')%26 +(int)'a');// shifting the respective letter by the value the key holds
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(charArray);
    }


}
}
```

And the output is,

```
defabc
tzhgy
```

**Edit:**

If you are considering about negative shifts, you can add below check inside the for loop. So if the new letter is smaller than 'a', it will convert the letter to correct letter.

```
if (charArray[j] < 'a'){
charArray[j] += 26;
 }
```

Completely updated code is below.

```
public class C {
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Encrypt(new String[]
                {
                        "",
                        "",
                        "-1",
                        "abcxyz",
                        "qwedv"
                });

    }

    public static void Encrypt(String[] args){

        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++) { // repeat the core program until all arguments were processed once

            int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); // save given key into int variable



            char[] charArray = args[i].toCharArray(); // argument from String to charArray
            int j = 0;
            for (char c : charArray) { // iterate through the Array by using a for-each loop
                if (Character.isLetter(c)) { // ascertain that only letters are alternated
                    charArray[j] = (char) ((c + k - (int)'a')%26 +(int)'a');// shifting the respective letter by the value the key holds
                    if (charArray[j] < 'a'){
                        charArray[j] += 26;
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println(charArray);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: for me it doesn't work properly especially when I use negative values for the shift

Comment: @GR33NTE4 I've changed code. Now it's also working for negative shifts.

Comment: You're a genius, thanks!